# Changing Blending Options for One layer group Only Adobe Photoshop

Tags: adobe, photoshop, blending

I am working on designing the interface for a game, what i did was to make 4 groups of layers. now i want to make some changes in blending options for a specific group of layers, but when i make some changes in one group layer, it is a changed in all of the four groups. 
P.S i designed one group of layers, the other three are copies of the 1st layers, but are rotated.

Comment: Could you upload an example PSD. Just remember that `blending options` affects all the layers below the modified layer.